# When using MigLayout, how would a 3rd int parameter to `add` affect layout?

Tags: java, swing, miglayout, jlayeredpane

For example:

```
layeredPane.setLayout(new MigLayout());
layeredPane.add(component, "pos 50 50, width 100, height 100", 0);
```

The `0` in this case does affect the component's layering, but I can't seem to figure out exactly how. I would like to overlay components, but because there is the second layout constraint for the `MigLayout`, I can't combine layering and positioning as usual with a `JLayeredPane`. Thanks

Comment: I don't think this code would work. You can't add a MigLayout object to a LayeredPane.

Comment: Apologies, my mistake. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html) haven't got implemented `LayoutManager` then there you have to [setBounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) or [setSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) by default, first parameter in constructor is used for `JComponents`, second for Type of Layer,

Comment: Check edit. The code works and the third parameter does affect the overlaying of the components added to it - I would just like to know if anyone knows exactly *how* it affects it.

Comment: @paranoid-android second params is for LayersType <DEFAULT_LAYER, PALETTE_LAYER, MODAL_LAYER, POPUP_LAYER, DRAG_LAYER>

Comment: How would arbitrary int values for LayersType affect component order (z-axis) in that case?

Comment: @paranoid-android good catch, really I haven't any idea, maybe you mixing add(JComponent, int (order)) with add(JComponent, layertype), add component with method setLayer(Component c, int layer, int position)

Comment: That's a really good idea, wasn't aware of `setLayer(Component c, int layer, int position)`. Should read the api more.. Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: Hi all.  I took a look at the "setLayer( ... , int position ) constructor.  Unfortunately it did not solve my problem.  In my case I have a nice frame design with everything looking great.  Except I need a layered pane for my main display area.

WHEN I add the first layer (deeper layer, background) things are "GO".  Sadly when I add a second overlay, layer -- Things *crash*

I accept that things that 'don't work' will break.  I find it frustrating that using the layered pane is such a problem if I need to use the miglayout manager too.  Why?

Comment: put JPanel to the layer, then add JComponents by using MigLayout to JPanel